# Packaging multiple rpms in one file

Tags: linux, installation, rpm

Is it possible to paqckage multiple rpms into one file. I have got two bundles one of which requires that the other be installed. I would like to create a single installable out of them in such a way that this installer will first invoke pkg 1 and then install pkg 2. Is this possible? What about deb packages? Sorry if it a basic question. I have not worked with installers on Linux before. I have created Windows installers. There you can create two merge modules (.msm) and package them into a standalone installer (.msi) and specify the order of execution. I am looking for similar functionality on Linux.

EDIT: I think the question was not clear enough. Let me try to rephrase it. I have a bunch of runtime libraries which is currently shipped as a standalone installer. Another team develops products which use these libraries at runtime. I now want to provide the libraries to the product team in some form (sub-package) which they can include with their installer and configure their installer to install my sub-package first. Both packages should be available locally to the end user. They are not available on any repository and cannot be pulled down from the net at install time.

Comment: +1 Good question, but the answers doesn't. Will wait for the good one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try packaging them into a self extraction bash script. You won't have to modify or aggregate the  libraries and rpms together. This should yield an executable file that can be included in another installation process. The last step of the extraction should be to call "rpm -i" with the rpm files as arguments.

Reference on building a self extracting bash script:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818

Comment: That wouldn't serve the same purpose as what I think the OP desired: that the user downloading a single file be greeted with a software "store" application to install it in one click.  Most systems (understandably) require users to chmod +x shell scripts before allowing their execution, breaking the "one click install" user experience that can be provided by a RPM package file.

Answer (score 0):

First : you don't have to repackage anything, especially not if your application uses some external libraries. You just have to mention in your recipe that your RPM (or DEB) *depends* on the other one. Both apt-get (for deb) and yum (for rpm) will check these dependencies and install them if needed.

See :
http://rpm5.org/docs/api/dependencies.html (rpm) and http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/How-to-make-deb-packages/ (deb)

(These were just the first ones I found, you can find better resources out there :p).

Comment: If your application is split into multiple components that depend on each other (and come from the same external repository), you cannot simply Require them in the spec file.  You'll have to merge them into a single spec file to achieve a "one click install" such as used by Google Chrome and others.